# Japanese Wikipedia categories DAG defined in "categorylinks" table has a cycle

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

I have found a reference cycle in the DAG defined by "categorylinks" and "page" tables inside the japanese Wikipedia database.
Is this a bug in the data?

Page ids reference cycle:

`2904319 -> 133683 -> 988775 -> 424676 -> 2904319`

`(行動 -> 生活 -> 人間関係 -> コミュニケーション -> 行動)`

I am considering only sub-categories (page_namespace = 14).
In the Wiki Category documentation it explicitly states that:

> All categories (except root category 1) should be contained in at least one other category, and there should be no cycles (i.e. a category should not contain itself, directly or indirectly).

Could the data be broken?
Am I misunderstanding anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is probably not broken. *There is nothing in MediaWiki that prevents category loops, or cycles.* Category structures like `A < B < C < A` are valid, and not uncommon in MediaWiki installations. Categories can also be orphaned, not belonging to any category.

The text you are quoting is not from the MediaWiki documentation, but from a **Wikimedia** help page. It refers to a recommendation by Wikimedia to try and keep categories hierarchical on Wikimedia wikis (e.g. Wikipedia). However, as this depends on the editors, you will find plenty of exceptions in any major Wikimedia wiki. Sometimes they are unintentional, and sometimes they are considered acceptable by the community for one reason or another.

A more relevant place to look in your case, is the corresponding help page, and the policy page for categories on Japanese Wikipedia. You'll find them here:

- [Help:カテゴリ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA)
- [Wikipedia:カテゴリの方針](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E3%82%AB%E3%83%86%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AE%E6%96%B9%E9%87%9D)

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the official docs.  Actually in the japanese page too it is stated that "you should be careful not to create category loops", but I guess since it is not enforced, you cannot assume there aren't.